# how to add nofollow tag to links in joomla3.2

Tags: performance, joomla, joomla3.0, nofollow

I have joomla 3.2 site. I have included many sidebars on different pages. Now i want to assign the `nofollow` tag to all the links of sidebar. so, how can i add `rel=nofollow tag` to all those links?

[here's link to mysite](http://joomla5.guru99.com/abap-tutorial.html)

and [here's screenshot of my issue](http://screencast.com/t/ZQBjUXsSr)

Please help me to solve this issue.

Regards

Comment: Have you checked here? [nofollow extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/nofollow)

Comment: These are internal links and i want to assign rel="nofollow" to all these links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things you can do:

1. In your menu manager, open menu item, then select **Metadata tab** and change option of **Robots** field. This won't add rel=nofollow tag to your link, but destination page will have meta tag nofollow.
2. If you REALLY want to add rel=nofollow, create your menu output template override by:

2.1 Create (if it doesn't exists) **templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/mod_menu** folder (if folder exists - go to step 2.3)

2.2 Copy ALL files from **modules/mod_menu/tmpl** to your folder **templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/mod_menu**

2.3 Open files default_component.php, default_url.php, and override link by adding rel="nofollow" where  tags are built.

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: hi di3sel, I have implemented your second step and it's worked, thanks a lot.